# Signing an oAuth request with HMAC-SHA1

Tags: ios, oauth, hmacsha1

I'm struggling on iOS to sign an oAuth request with oAuth. I don't need to sign on behalf of a user, so I just have my app's key/secret from my provider. Is there an iOS library or 3rd party library which I can use to just generate the nonce, timestamp and sign the request?

Comment: How could you solve your problem? I am facing "Invalid signature" problem and I do not know how to generate the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the Objective-C library [oauthconsumer](http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer) can be of help?

Found here: http://oauth.net/code/

Comment: Thanks, that was a help but still needed considerable tweaking I found.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues. I found libraries like the one linked above a little verbose for what I needed. I ended up creating my own signature following these steps from Twitter: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature. They provide really clear steps on how to create the signature.